# Ignore part of match in `re.split`

Tags: python, regex

Input is a two-sentence string:

```
s = 'Sentence 1 here.  This sentence contains 1 fl. oz. but is one sentence.'
```

I'd like to `.split` `s` into sentences based on the logic that:

- sentences end with one or more periods, exclamation marks, questions marks, or period+quotation mark
- and are then followed by 1+ whitespace characters and a capitalized alpha character.

Desired result:

```
['Sentence 1 here.', 'This sentence contains 1 fl. oz. but is one sentence.']
```

Also okay:

```
['Sentence 1 here', 'This sentence contains 1 fl. oz. but is one sentence.']
```

But I currently chop off the 0th element of each sentence because the uppercase character is captured:

```
import re
END_SENT = re.compile(r'[.!?(.")]+[ ]+[A-Z]')
print(END_SENT.split(s))
['Sentence 1 here', 'his sentence contains 1 fl. oz. but is one sentence.']
```

Notice the missing *T*.  How can I tell `.split` to ignore certain elements of the compiled pattern?

Comment: Try `'[.!?(.")]+[ ]+(?=[A-Z])'`

Comment: by the way anything included in `[]` is character set. Not a sequence so you have a char set of `.`,`!`,`?`,`(`,`.`,`"`,`)` ==> `.`,`!`,`?`,`(`,`"`,`)`

Comment: This is exactly what lookahead is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((?<=[.!?])|(?<=\.\")) +(?=[A-Z])
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rNPepO/1).

Although I would suggest the below to allow quotes to be followed by any of .!? to be a split condition

```
((?<=[.!?])|(?<=[.!?]\")) +(?=[A-Z])
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/plzjLO/1).

---

**Explanation**

The common stuff in both `+(?=[A-Z])`

```
' +'    #One or more spaces(The actual splitting chars used.)
(?=     #START positive look ahead check if it followed by this, but do not consume
[A-Z]   #Any capitalized alphabet
)       #END positive look ahead
```

The conditions for what comes before the space
**For Solution1**

```
(     #GROUP START
(?<=  #START Positive look behind, Make sure this comes before but do not consume
[.!?] #any one of these chars should come before the splitting space
)     #END positive look behind
|     #OR condition this is also the reason we had to put all this in GROUP
(?<=  #START Positive look behind,
\.\"  #splitting space could precede by .", covering a condition that is not by the previous set of . or ! or ?
)     #END positive look behind
)     #END GROUP
```

**For Solution2**

```
(             #GROUP START
(?<=[.!?])    #Same as the previous look behind
|             #OR condition
(?<=[.!?]\")  #Only difference here is that we are allowing quote after any of . or ! or ? 
)             #GROUP END
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to describe the sentence than trying to identify the delimiter. So instead of `re.split` try with `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'([^.?!\s].*?[.?!]*)\s*(?![^A-Z])', s)
```

To preserve the next uppercase letter, the pattern uses a lookahead that is only a test and doesn't consume characters.

details:

```
(     # capture group: re.findall return only the capture group content if any
    [^.?!\s]   # the first character isn't a space or a punctuation character
    .*?        # a non-greedy quantifier
    [.?!]*     # eventual punctuation characters
)
\s*            # zero or more white-spaces
(?![^A-Z])     # not followed by a character that isn't a uppercase letter
               # (this includes an uppercase letter and the end of the string)
```

Obviously, for more complicated cases with abbreviations, names, etc., you have to use tools like nltk or any other nlp tools trained with dictionaries.

Comment: Should be `\s+` according to OP's description.

Comment: I would change the end condition from `(?![^A-Z])` to `(?![^A-Z\"])`. So that it accommodates a sentence that starts with a quotation `"`.

Comment: @bulbus: to be clear, there are thousand of reasons this pattern can be wrong, that's why I added a line about nlp tools. Trying to handle the quote may also add errors.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sure, the reason I suggested it because OP had this condition.